# Font rendering Bug in SDL .NET? Or just my code?

Tags: c#, sdl, game-engine, system.drawing, game-physics

```
/// <summary>
/// Simple UI TextBox Class. For displaying messages in 2D Games
/// </summary>
class TextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Text"> The text of the TextBox</param>
    public TextBox(string Text = "", int w = 400, int h = 200)
    {
        this.Text = Text;
        textNext = string.Empty;

        try { Surface = new Surface(w, h); }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            Events.QuitApplication();
        }

        Offset = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 30);
        FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        Surface.Fill(BackColor);

        try { Font = new Font(@"data\font\AllerDisplay.ttf", 16); }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            Events.QuitApplication();
        }

        Visible = true;
        MaxLines = 6;
        AcceptKey = Key.Return;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Locks and wraps up the text box.
    /// Text, Size and Font changes take effect
    /// </summary>
    public void Lock()
    {
        Surface.Fill(BackColor); // clear the surface
        DrawText(); // draw the text
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(AcceptKey))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textNext))
            {
                Text = textNext;
                textNext = string.Empty;
                Lock();
            }
            else
            {
                Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps up and renders the text
    /// </summary>
    private void DrawText()
    {
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(Text.Length);

        // increment the size of each character
        for (var i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
        {
            x += Font.SizeText(Text[i].ToString()).Width;

            // if it exceeds the width of the box
            if (x > Surface.Width - Offset.X * 2)
            {
                Text = Text.Insert(i, "-\n");
                x = 0;
                y++;
            }

            // if the lines exceed the limit
            if (y > MaxLines)
            {
                // save the remaining lines for the next run
                var index = Text.LastIndexOf("-\n");
                textNext = Text.Substring(index);
                Text = Text.Substring(0, index);
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Text);

        // render the string and blit it onto Surface
        var surf = Font.Render(Text, FontColor);
        Surface.Blit(surf, Offset);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The remaining text which is to be displayed 
    /// on the next run of the text box
    /// </summary>
    string textNext;

    /// <summary>
    /// The text of the text box
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The background surface of the text box
    /// </summary>
    public Surface Surface
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maximum number of lines per text piece
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxLines
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // More irrelevant code...
}
```

Now the `DrawText()` method basically does a word wrap on the text. If the text is too big to be displayed in a single box part of it is stored and displayed in a re-run. Now the problem is, the second time I call Font.Render, I get vertically displayed text for some reason. For example:

```
            textBox = new TextBox(
@"Please note that this Tutorial is not for the absolute beginner. I assume that you already can code fluent in C# and that you are able to understand code when reading them. I will not explain every single line of code when it should be clear what it's doing. Also please note that i am not a native speaker, so there are for sure many grammatical errors in this text (which are maybe corrected in the future when i find them ;-)");

            textBox.Lock();
```

Now the output I get is:
[image: Output 1]
[image: Output 2]

So why exactly is the second part of the text displayed vertically? I tried checking if my word wrap function worked properly, perhaps the vertical orientation was caused by '\n' inserts. However, it was working perfectly. It only added an '\n' at the right place. So there's probably some problem with the font rendering.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to see what changes?

Comment: @leppie the debugger detects no problems.